# Vue.js import from problems

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

Well,  a few times I use vue-cli I have no problem on importing component or just a simpe module using ampersand symbol like

```
import API_URL from '@/components/blablabla'
```

So I clone vue js adminlte,  and when I try to import using ampersand symbol somehow It wont resolve the component or module,  any ideas why?

Thx for all help

Comment: My guess is that the adminlte project has configured the `resolve.alias` object in the webpack config differently than what gets set up via vue-cli. What does your webpack configuration file look like?

Comment: sorry for late reply,  well i guess its the path resolver in the webpack config file.  I have to add '@' alias. Thank you @thanksd